# C++ polymorphic cloning with templated class. Can't use cloned object as argument in function

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, polymorphism, clone

I have a templated class `Specie< T>` that derives from a base class `Animal`. I created a vector of pointers to Animal in order to store different types of objects `Specie<T>` in the same vector. T can be Dog, Cat, etc...

Now I want to use some element of the vector as argument in a templated function. I wrote different specializations of the function for the different template parameter T so the behaviour is different for each `Specie<T>`. In order to get the right type of each object from the vector, I used the polymorphic cloning. It works well, I get the right type of object `Specie<T>` (see very short tests below). However, when I want to use an element of the vector as an argument of the templated function, it does not work.

```
// Base class
class Animal{

 public:
  virtual ~Animal() {}

  virtual Animal *clone() = 0;
  virtual void action() = 0;

};


// Specific types of animals. Forward declaration
class Dog;
class Cat;



// Templated derived class Specie
template <class T>
class Specie : public Animal{

public:
    Specie<T> *clone();

    void action();

};





template <class T>
Specie<T> * Specie<T>::clone() {

   std::cout << "Cloning a Specie<T>" << std::endl;
   return new Specie<T>(*this);

}



// Specialization of templated function action() for Dog
template <>
void Specie<Dog>::action(){

  std::cout << "Wouaf !" << std::endl;

}


// Specialization of templated function action() for Cat
template <>
void Specie<Cat>::action(){

  std::cout << "Miaouuu !" << std::endl;

}




class Interaction{

public:

  template <class T1>
  static void DoSomething(Specie<T1>);

};



// Specialization of templated function DoSomething() for Dog
template <>
void Interaction::DoSomething(Specie<Dog> obj){

std::cout << "Interact with Dog !" << std::endl;

}


// Specialization of templated function DoSomething() for Cat
template <>
void Interaction::DoSomething(Specie<Cat> obj){

std::cout << "Interact with Cat !" << std::endl;

}




int main(){


 Specie<Cat> HelloKitty;
 Specie<Dog> Bobby;

 Animal *Dingo = new Specie<Dog>();

 Animal *Tom = new Specie<Cat>();

// cloning Dingo
 Animal *UnknownAnimal = Dingo->clone();

// We check the type is correct after cloning
 UnknownAnimal->action();

// We check that DoSomething recognizes correctly the type of objects
// and uses the proper specialization
 Interaction::DoSomething(Bobby);
 Interaction::DoSomething(HelloKitty);




// Vector of pointers to Animals
 std::vector<Animal *> myanimals;

// We add an object of type Specie<Dog> and an object
// of type Specie<Cat> to the vector

 myanimals.push_back(&Bobby);
 myanimals.push_back(&HelloKitty);



 Animal *UnknownAnimal2 = myanimals[1]->clone();

// We check the type is correct after cloning
 UnknownAnimal2->action();



// NOW WE TRY TO USE THE ELEMENT FROM VECTOR AS ARGUMENT OF 
// SPECIALIZED FUNCTION. DOES NOT WORK.
 Interaction::DoSomething(*(myanimals[0]->clone()));



  return 0;
}
```

> error: no instance of function template "Interaction::DoSomething"
>   matches the argument list
>
> argument types are: (Animal)    Interaction::DoSomething(*(myanimals[0]->clone()));

What is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the result of `clone()` is still of type `Animal*`, it can be overridden in subclasses thanks to covariance of return types, but it has no effect when calling the member function in context of a base class

Comment: In addition to @PiotrSkotnicki 's comment: You don't have a `Interaction::DoSomething` accepting an object of type `Animal`

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yes, that's right. I do not define Interaction::DoSomething(Animal) because it only makes sense with specific animals (Dog, Cat, ...). The interaction changes with each animal type. Therefore I only define Interaction::DoSomething(Specie<T>).

Comment: @Xtof I understand what you are trying to achieve, but it won't work this way. The only solution I could think of would be to define a intermediate class between Animal and Species (e.g. `InteractableAnimal`) and use this class instead of Animal.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Would you have an example to show me of what you are suggesting ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the base class function `virtual Animal *clone() = 0;` which always seems to return an `Animal`.

The function overloading works at compile time, and cannot change the call depending on the dynamic type of the argument. For that you need virtual function calls.

Comment: Yes but in the templated class Specie, the return type of clone() is Specie<T>. That works fine.

Comment: @Xtof the *dynamic* type is `Specie<T>*`, but the *static* type of calling `clone` on an `Animal*` is `Animal*` .

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using an intermediate class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Animal {

public:
    virtual ~Animal() {}
    virtual Animal *clone() = 0;
};

class InteractionAnimal : public Animal {
public:
    virtual ~InteractionAnimal() {}

    virtual InteractionAnimal *clone() = 0;
    virtual void action() const = 0;
};


// Specific types of animals. Forward declaration
class Dog;
class Cat;



// Templated derived class Specie
template <class T>
class Specie : public InteractionAnimal {

public:
    Specie<T> *clone();

    void action() const;

};

template <class T>
Specie<T> * Specie<T>::clone() {

    std::cout << "Cloning a Specie<T>" << std::endl;
    return new Specie<T>(*this);

}

// Specialization of templated function action() for Dog
template <>
void Specie<Dog>::action() const {

    std::cout << "Wouaf !" << std::endl;

}


// Specialization of templated function action() for Cat
template <>
void Specie<Cat>::action() const {

    std::cout << "Miaouuu !" << std::endl;

}




class Interaction {

public:
    static void DoSomething(const InteractionAnimal& animal) {
        //Will be called when Type is not fully known
        animal.action();
    }

};

int main() {


    Specie<Cat> HelloKitty;
    Specie<Dog> Bobby;

    InteractionAnimal *Dingo = new Specie<Dog>();

    InteractionAnimal *Tom = new Specie<Cat>();

    // cloning Dingo
    InteractionAnimal *UnknownAnimal = Dingo->clone();

    // We check the type is correct after cloning
    UnknownAnimal->action();

    // We check that DoSomething recognizes correctly the type of objects
    // and uses the proper specialization
    Interaction::DoSomething(Bobby);
    Interaction::DoSomething(HelloKitty);




    // Vector of pointers to Animals
    std::vector<InteractionAnimal *> myanimals;

    // We add an object of type Specie<Dog> and an object
    // of type Specie<Cat> to the vector

    myanimals.push_back(&Bobby);
    myanimals.push_back(&HelloKitty);



    InteractionAnimal *UnknownAnimal2 = myanimals[1]->clone();

    // We check the type is correct after cloning
    UnknownAnimal2->action();



    // NOW WE TRY TO USE THE ELEMENT FROM VECTOR AS ARGUMENT OF 
    // SPECIALIZED FUNCTION. DOES NOT WORK.
    Interaction::DoSomething(*(myanimals[0]->clone()));



    return 0;
}
```

I have removed the specialized `DoSomething` functions as they wouldn't be called for `InteractiveAnimal` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and it works even without the intermediate InteractionAnimal class. What I needed was to modify the DoSomething as you did, which now accepts a pointer to Animal * as argument, and then inside launches the proper action(). A part of the problem is solved. What I need now is to define an action between two elements of the vector, that is, the proper action(Animal *obj1, Animal *obj2) should be executed depending of the type of both arguments: action(Cat, Dog); action(Cat, Bird); action(Bird, Fish), etc...

Comment: That won't work with templates. You don't know the derived type of the object when you have an `Animal` objects only.

Maybe you should open up another question to avoid confusion within this page.

Comment: Yes, good idea. Meanwhile I will look at what can be done with double dispatch.